# How to add www. to requesting URL on a Drupal site?

Tags: http, drupal

I'd like to redirect, for example:

```
http://example.com/        ->  http//www.example.com/
http://example.com/node/1  ->  http://www.example.com/node/1
https://example.com/cart   ->  https://www.example.com/cart
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a Drupal specific question. Although it can be done at the Drupal level (ie. the PHP application level) it should be done at the HTTP server level (as done in the accepted answer). The original question does not give enough information, the crucial one being the HTTP server used. For each HTTP server software, the answer will be different. The accepted answer only works for Apache httpd with mod_rewrite. And only if configured to allow .htaccess to contains mod_rewrite configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the root directory of your Drupal site, check out the comments in the .htaccess file (in the `# Various rewrite rules` section. Specifically, look for the following lines:

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# adapt and uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

... and uncomment those last two, replacing example.com with the appropriate domain name.